How can I check from Neovim lua if a given option is supported?
The option 'messagesopt' is currently only in nightly builds of Neovim like (v0.11.0-dev-1388+g39781be14b).
I want to perform vim.opt.messagesopt = 'wait:2000,history:40' but only if the current Neovim supports it.
I know I can use vim.fn.has('xxx') to check for features.
Is there anything similar to check for options?

You can use exists() to check for an option:
if vim.fn.exists("&messagesopt") == 1 then
  vim.opt.messagesopt='wait:2000,history:50' 
end

In order to call the vimscript exists() function you need to use the vim.fn.exists() and be aware that it will return 0 or 1 not true/false like in vimscript. The input to exists() is a string in this case &option-name (so &messagesopt in your case) as specified on the :h exists():

&option-name: Vim option (only checks if it exists, not if it really works)

